# how to get the src file to be processed by annotation processor/annotation processing tool?

Tags: annotation-processing

I have a need to keep original source file unchanged after annotation processing, is it possible to get the original file stored in a/b/c/A.java to before being processed?

for example I have a class:

```
@xxx
class A {
}
```

I would like to get the original source code of the file before being processed. i tried to use
`processingEnv.getFiler().getResource` but it does not seem to work
Thanks.

Comment: Annotation processors cannot modify any files using the public APIs. Lombok is a noteworthy cases of an annotation processor which uses internal APIs of the compiler to mdofiy the result, through. Can you be more specific about what you mean with *unchanged source files*?

Comment: (I mean because there should not exist any changed source files.)